# Hibernate Batch Insert not working in MySql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying batch insert using hibernate in spring batch. I have read many answers in this site and then tried to apply the batch insert logic but was met with an exception. I have posted my code below. Please help me solve this.
Below is my entity object.

```
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Immutable;

@Entity
@Table(name = "vendor_source")
@Immutable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY, region = "vendorSourceRegion")
public class VendorSource implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7529960788000388791L;
    private String sourceCode;
    private String sourceName;
    private Date createTime = new Date();
    private Date updateTime = new Date();
    private String createId = " ";
    private String updateId = " ";

    public VendorSource() {

    }

    public VendorSource(String sourceCode, String sourceName, String filler, Date createTime, Date updateTime,
            String createId, String updateId) {
        super();
        this.sourceCode = sourceCode;
        this.sourceName = sourceName;
        this.createTime = createTime;
        this.updateTime = updateTime;
        this.createId = createId;
        this.updateId = updateId;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "source_code", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 1)
    public String getSourceCode() {
        return sourceCode;
    }

    public void setSourceCode(String sourceCode) {
        this.sourceCode = sourceCode;
    }

    @Column(name = "source_name", nullable = false, length = 35)
    public String getSourceName() {
        return sourceName;
    }

    public void setSourceName(String sourceName) {
        this.sourceName = sourceName;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "create_time", nullable = false, length = 19)
    public Date getCreateTime() {
        return this.createTime;
    }

    public void setCreateTime(Date createTime) {
        this.createTime = createTime;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "update_time", nullable = false, length = 19)
    public Date getUpdateTime() {
        return this.updateTime;
    }

    public void setUpdateTime(Date updateTime) {
        this.updateTime = updateTime;
    }

    @Column(name = "create_id", nullable = false, length = 254)
    public String getCreateId() {
        return this.createId;
    }

    public void setCreateId(String createId) {
        this.createId = createId;
    }

    @Column(name = "update_id", nullable = false, length = 254)
    public String getUpdateId() {
        return this.updateId;
    }

    public void setUpdateId(String updateId) {
        this.updateId = updateId;
    }
}
```

I have also set these properties in my session factory

```
 hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=20
 hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data=true
 hibernate.order_inserts=true
 hibernate.order_updates=true
```

Here is my writer code:

```
Session session = spinSessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
        long prev = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        for(VendorSource item:items){
            i++;
            session.save(item);
            if(i%20==0){
                session.flush();
                session.clear();
            }
        }
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
```

**I am using MySQl so I also set the property "rewriteBatchedStatements=true" in my connection URL.**
I am getting the following exception while running the code:

```
Hibernate: insert into vendor_source (create_id, create_time, source_name, update_id, update_time, source_code) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into vendor_source (create_id, create_time, source_name, update_id, update_time, source_code) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into vendor_source (create_id, create_time, source_name, update_id, update_time, source_code) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into vendor_source (create_id, create_time, source_name, update_id, update_time, source_code) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into vendor_source (create_id, create_time, source_name, update_id, update_time, source_code) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into vendor_source (create_id, create_time, source_name, update_id, update_time, source_code) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into vendor_source (create_id, create_time, source_name, update_id, update_time, source_code) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into vendor_source (create_id, create_time, source_name, update_id, update_time, source_code) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into vendor_source (create_id, create_time, source_name, update_id, update_time, source_code) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into vendor_source (create_id, create_time, source_name, update_id, update_time, source_code) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into vendor_source (create_id, create_time, source_name, update_id, update_time, source_code) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into vendor_source (create_id, create_time, source_name, update_id, update_time, source_code) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into vendor_source (create_id, create_time, source_name, update_id, update_time, source_code) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into vendor_source (create_id, create_time, source_name, update_id, update_time, source_code) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into vendor_source (create_id, create_time, source_name, update_id, update_time, source_code) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into vendor_source (create_id, create_time, source_name, update_id, update_time, source_code) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into vendor_source (create_id, create_time, source_name, update_id, update_time, source_code) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into vendor_source (create_id, create_time, source_name, update_id, update_time, source_code) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into vendor_source (create_id, create_time, source_name, update_id, update_time, source_code) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into vendor_source (create_id, create_time, source_name, update_id, update_time, source_code) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2017-10-03 16:15:45.571 ERROR [BatchingBatch] - HHH000315: Exception executing batch [Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 20; expected: 1]
2017-10-03 16:15:45.584 ERROR [AbstractStep] - Encountered an error executing the step
org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchedTooManyRowsAffectedException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 20; expected: 1
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.checkBatched(Expectations.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.Expectations$BasicExpectation.verifyOutcome(Expectations.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.checkRowCounts(BatchingBatch.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.performExecution(BatchingBatch.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch.addToBatch(BatchingBatch.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3124)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3581)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
    at com.searshc.hs.item.master.update.vendor.charges.writer.CustomWriter.write(CustomWriter.java:36)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:175)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doWrite(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:151)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.write(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:274)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:199)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:75)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:395)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:267)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:77)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:368)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:253)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:195)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:137)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.JobFlowExecutor.executeStep(JobFlowExecutor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.state.StepState.handle(StepState.java:60)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.resume(SimpleFlow.java:152)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.start(SimpleFlow.java:131)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:301)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:134)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:127)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.start(CommandLineJobRunner.java:351)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.main(CommandLineJobRunner.java:577)
```

**Before I put the "rewriteBatchedStatements=true" property, My code was working fine but batching was not working. After inserting the property now my code is throwing exception. Please provide any insight on this.**

Comment: I'm not sure how do you prepare `items` collection. If you provide its code, that might be helpful to identify the problem.

Comment: I am reading a file using flat file reader to read every line and map it to an object of VendorSource. Then in my customWriter I am receiving a list of those which is named item here. Each object is of type VendorSource(for which source code is provided).

Comment: If I don't use "rewriteBatchedStatements=true", will the sql be still batched?

Comment: Can you please share the file? Basically I want to see how your objects are created & what fields are set in all the objects.

Comment: You must set `rewriteBatchedStatements` to `true` if you're using MySql. So that the driver will be enabled to detect inserts to the same table that can be combined into a single insert statement

Comment: Thanks @RAS for your answers. I found the soution, I just needed to updated my mysql connector version from 5.1.28 to 5.1.36

Comment: Why to 5.1.36, why not to the latest version (5.1.44)?

Comment: Mark, as 5.1.36 was working for me, I did not try other latest version. I will try the latest one and see if it works too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the driver was not giving correct row count for some reason. Updating MySql connector from 5.1.28 to 5.1.36 solved the problem. Now I can see the statements being batched.